# Get Friday before specific date using GNU date

Tags: bash, date, gnu

Using the GNU date command line utility, I know:

- how to substract 3 days from any given date:
  `date -d "20110405 -3 days" "+%Y%m%d"`
  `20110402`
- how to get the last Friday from today:
  `date -d "last friday" "+%Y%m%d"`
  `20110408`

But I don't know how to get the last Friday from any given date:
`date -d "20110405 last Friday" "+%Y%m%d"`
Simply returns the given date: `20110405`

Any ideas on how to do this? If a one-liner is not possible a few lines of script would also be helpful.

Answer (score 5):

Ugly, but one line:

<strike>`date -d "20110405 -2 days -$(date -d '20110405' '+%w') days" "+%Y%m%d"`</strike>

**EDIT**: See comments.

```
date -d "20110405 -$(date -d "20110405 +2 days" +%u) days" "+%Y%m%d"
```

Explanation:

- `%u` returns day of the week (1-7). Subtracting this many days from any date will always take you to the previous Sunday.
- `+2 days` means we will be subtracting `%u + 2`, 2 days before last Sunday, i.e. last Friday.

I don't like that it repeats the date string, but hopefully it goes some way to helping.

Comment: You may omit part of your quoting: `date -d "20100405 -2 days -$(date -d 20100405 +%w) days" +%Y%m%d`

Comment: Hmm that's an idea but it doesn't work on Saturdays: it will return the Friday 8 days before.
Anyway I'll use this trick and make some tests to check the day of the week.
Thanks.

Comment: Oops, try this: `date -d "20110405 -$(date -d "20110405 +2 days" +%u) days" "+%Y%m%d"`.

Answer (score 2):

Script example (based on the accepted answer)

```
DT="20170601"
# get the Friday before $DT
# expected value is 20170526
date -d "$DT -`date -d "$DT +2 days" +%u` days" "+%Y%m%d"
```

Further examples, using undocumented features of GNU date (from [unix.com](http://www.unix.com/tips-and-tutorials/31944-simple-date-time-calulation-bash.html))

```
# assign a value to the variable DT for the examples below
DT="2006-10-01 06:55:55"
echo $DT

# add 2 days, one hour and 5 sec to any date
date --date "$DT  2 days 1 hour 5 sec"

# subtract from any date
date --date "$DT 3 days 5 hours 10 sec ago"
date --date "$DT -3 days -5 hours -10 sec"

# or any mix of +/-. What will be the date in 3 months less 5 days?
date --date "now +3 months -5 days"
```