# format a number string to date

Tags: bash, date, variables, sh

In a bash script, I have a variable like :

```
date=20140131
```

which means 31 Jan 2014. How can I add one day to it? I mean how can I add one value to "date" to change it to "**20140201**" (1 Fab 2014) not "**20140132**"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with `GNU date`

```
$  d=20140131
$  date -d "$d +1 day" +%Y%m%d

20140201
```

If you don't have `gnu date`, here is  the script I used mostly (refer http://www.unix.com/16559-post2.html )

so if you need get the next day of 20140131, you can run:

```
datecalc -a 2014 01 31 + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

here you go:

```
kent$  echo $d
20140131

kent$  date -d"$d +1 day" +%Y%m%d
20140201
```

Answer (score 1):

well, you need to use [GNU/date](http://linux.math.tifr.res.in/manuals/man/date.html), and not the standard unix date, because it implements date arithmetics unlike the original unix date, and then all you need is to do :

```
% date=20140131
% date -d "$date + 1 day"
Sat Feb  1 00:00:00 CET 2014
```

and if you want to avoid any formatting problem, you can specify the format using:

```
% date -d "$date + 1 day" '+%Y%m%d' 
20140201
```

There are a few articles about having fun with gnu/date arithmetics:

- http://linuxcommando.blogspot.com/2009/11/fun-with-date-arithmetic.html‎
- [Date calculation using GNU date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655026/date-calculation-using-gnu-date)
- http://www.walkernews.net/2007/06/03/date-arithmetic-in-linux-shell-scripts/

Answer (score 1):

try this solution:

**I misunderstood it first**

**UPDATE**

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                      
datee="20140131"
DATE=`date -d"$datee +1 day" +%Y%m%d`
echo $DATE
```

**OR**

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                      
datee="20140131"
DATE=$(date -d"$datee +1 day" +%Y%m%d)
echo $DATE
```

**result is:**

```
20140201
```